# Can't set the text on a UILabel controlled by a custom UIViewController

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotationview

I have a mapkit application, where I've created a custom callout view.  I can't seem to get the labels on the view to update though.  Here's my setup:

I have a custom annotation class called VendorAnnotation with 5 string properties (phone and 4 address lines).  The VendorAnnotation objects have their rightCalloutAccessoryView set to a UIButton.  In the delegate method: 
`` `(void)mapView:(MKMapVIew *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessroyControlTapped:(UIControl *)control{} ``
I access the 5 strings via the annotations properties:
    VendorAnnotation v = (VendorAnnotation*) view.annotation;
Then I have:
    `DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithDetails:v.phone add1:v.add1 add2:v.add2 add3:v.add3 add4:v.add4];`
I know by stepping through, that at this point these string properties (v.*) have accurate values.
The problem is, this initWithDetails method doesn't set the label texts.  Here is my code for the DetailViewController class:

DetailViewController.h:

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
{
  IBOutlet UILabel *_phone;
  IBOutlet UILabel *_add1;
  IBOutlet UILabel *_add2;
  IBOutlet UILabel *_add3;
  IBOutlet UILabel *_add4;
}


- (id)initWithDetails:(NSString *)p add1:(NSString *)a add2:(NSString *)aa add3:(NSString *)aaa add4:(NSString *)aaaa;
@end
```

DetailViewController.m:

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation DetailViewController


- (id)initWithDetails:(NSString *)p add1:(NSString *)a add2:(NSString *)aa add3:(NSString *)aaa add4:(NSString *)aaaa

{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    [_phone setText:p];
    [_add1 setText:a];
    [_add2 setText:aa];
    [_add3 setText:aaa];
    [_add4 setText:aaaa];
  }
  return self;
}
```

I don't know why, but the labels' text property never gets set to the appropriate strings.  Please help.  I know it's something stupid, I'm new to objective C and iOS programming, but I don't see the problem.  I should probably mention that I have connected the labels on the .xib in IB to the appropriate IBOutlet properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe because "p", "a", "aa"... aren't initiated..

Try it on `- (void)viewDidLoad` instead init.

Or instead of using:

```
detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithDetails:v.phone add1:v.add1 add2:v.add2 add3:v.add3 add4:v.add4];
```

why don't you use the custom init method and then do something like this:

```
detailVC.YOUR_LABEL.text = @"Your TEXT";
```

or

```
detailVC.YOUR_LABEL.text = v.add1;
```

Comment: Duhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.....  I had already tried your second suggestion (to create the labels as properties and assign them that way.  That might have worked if I had done it after initialization.  Bottom line is that you are right, the view hasn't been loaded from the xib at the point that the init method is called.  I added string properties to the class, assigned those in the init method, and then set the label texts in the viewDidLoad method.  Worked like a charm!  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you don't have to create a strings properties.
Try to declare the IBOutlets as properties, connect them in IB.
Init DetailViewController With 'initWithNibName' and assign text after initialization.
that way the interface is loaded in initialization (I suppose it will work better, with less properties)

Answer (score 0):

Your outlet i-vars are nil's inside your custom initializer. That's why values are not set.